Energy of Domain Wall in field theory
It is well known that in the case of the Mexican hat potential in $D=(1+1)$, it is possible to find kink solutions that interpolate between the vacua of the theory. In the context of cosmology, these configurations are extended to $D=3+1$. Is the energy of the new extended domain walls infinite? I know that there's a finite surface density $\sigma=\int{T_{00}dx}$, however, since the field does not depend on let's say $x$ and $y$ integrating the energy density would yield an infinite energy. Am I overlooking something?

You calculate the energy per unit area of the domain wall. That is finite.
